# Matrix positive definite

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be both symmetric $ n \times n$ matrices, and $B \succ 0$;
$U$ be one $n \times q$ column orthogonal matrix ($n > q$).
Assume $$ 0 \preceq U^{T} A U \preceq U^{T} B U,$$
do we have the following inequality $$UU^{T}AUU^{T} \preceq B.$$

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 3 \\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix},
\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
(both are SPD). Let $U=[1,0]^T$. Then
$$
0\leq 5=U^TAU\leq U^TBU=5.
$$
But
$$
B-UU^TAUU^T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is indefinite.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Just premultiply by $U^T$ and postmultiply by $U$ after bringing $B$ over to the other side.  If $C \leq 0$ then $U^T C U\leq 0$ also.

Comment: I'm not vert undertand your expression. Could you clarify more detali?

Comment: But my question is juse reverse. Knowing $U^{T}CU \leq 0$, we need proof $C\leq 0$.